# R: How to use if statement with grepl

Tags: r, grepl

I am trying to categorize a data frame by determining if either of two variables contains certain elements.

What I want is "if column A or B contains x, then column C=1", "if column A or B contains y, column C=2" etc.

```
 df$C <- if(grepl("x", df$A, ignore.case = TRUE)), "1"
```

I get Error:

```
unexpected ',' in "df$C <- if(grepl("x", df$A, ignore.case = TRUE)), "1"
```

Comment: you are (probably) looking for `ifelse()`

Comment: please don't change your question if you're encountering a new problem after the one in the original question is solved

Answer (score 2):

We don't need a `,` in `if`.  Having said that, the `grepl` output is logical, which can be coerced to binary with `as.integer`

```
as.integer(grepl("x", df$A, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

If the number of rows is greater than 1, use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` for changing to different values or for complex logic